# Data extraction for time series, transform multiple netCDF files to spatRaster with terra in R

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, loop, terra

I would like to extract data from around 13,000 .nc files to create a time series of temperature global data in R. Each of my files contain a day worth of data of global SST (my variable of interest) at 5km by 5km resolution.

I would like to:

1. Extract all data and create Spat Rasters in case I need to create subsets based in a box of lon,lat coordinates and plot them.
2. Extract all time saeries of daily SST data for specific points in which I've got biological observations, again stored as lon,lat (x,y) points from a separate df.

After many different attempts, and running into memory allocation problems, I thought of creating a stack of spatRaster files from the .nc files. By transforming the .ncs to spatRaster and stacking them on a loop, my resulting spatRaster stack has nrows, ncols, nlayers but not ncells, which I find a bit odd and not sure if that's normal.

Can I extract the data from my stack if there are no ncells? Here is a bit of the transformation process and how each spatRaster looks.

```
files <- list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE, 
                    recursive = TRUE , pattern = "temp_v3.1_20\\d{6}\\.nc$")

rast1=rast("2000/temp_v3.1_20000101.nc")
rast1<-rast1["sst"]

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  tmp_rast = rast(files[i])
  tmp_rast<-tmp_rast["sst"]
  rast1<-c(rast1,tmp_rast)
}
```

Looking at rast 1 prior combining it with the other rasters it looks like this:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3600, 7200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +a=6378137 +rf=298.2572 +no_defs 
varname     : sst (sea surface temperature) 
name        : sst 
unit        : degrees_Celsius 
time        : 1985-01-01 12:00:00 UTC
```

when creating the stack it looks the same but shows around 8000 layers, each layer represents a day on my time series but I wonder now how to extract sst data for a specific (x,y) point for the entire time series. Do I need first to create a grid within the loop so each layer has its grid? Does it has to do with the spatRaster format? I've tried using raster package and the grid is automatically created, the only issue is that if I tried to create a brick with raster then I would have memory problems again due to the large number of files.

I'd really appreciate any direction on this as I'm relatively new to spatial analysis.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please elaborate why you'd like to extract ALL data from your nc files? What is the point to replicate your dataset? You should be able to create subsets easily - when needed - once your data was successfully imported to SpatRaster objects using `terra`. For extraction of values from your stack, you should be able to make use of `terra::extract()` - which I don't see being referenced yet.

Comment: I was trying to have all data available in case I had to plot my time series of different  lat,lon boxes (slices) but I wasn't really sure how to extract from a global nc a few slices of interest so I though it would be handy to extract all as a spatRaster and then crop

Comment: Maybe this is just a misunderstanding and you meant "getting data out of the nc files" rather than getting the raster cell values out of the rasters? Once you created a stack of raster data, you should be able to index relevant layers by time and/or crop them to your area of investigation. This can all be done as needed when needed, from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a showcase using SST data, but raster data content should not be an issue here from my point of view. I have been using the following approach to generate time series from raster data based on point locations (or polygon areas), exemplified using precipitation data, basically making use of `terra` in combination with `xts`:

```r
# download and unpack file
file <- "full_data_daily_v2022_10_2020.nc.gz"

utils::download.file(paste0("https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/GPCC/full_data_daily_v2022/", file), 
                     file)

R.utils::gunzip(file, remove = TRUE)

# read raster data and subset to specific layer
f <- list.files(pattern = "nc$")
f
#> "full_data_daily_v2022_10_2020.nc"

r <- terra::rast(f)

terra::varnames(r)
#> [1] "precip"              "interpolation_error" "numgauge"

r <- r["precip"]
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 360, 366  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : full_data_daily_v2022_10_2020.nc:precip 
#> varname     : precip (gpcc full data daily product version 2022 precipitation per grid) 
#> names       : precip_1, precip_2, precip_3, precip_4, precip_5, precip_6, ... 
#> unit        :   mm/day,   mm/day,   mm/day,   mm/day,   mm/day,   mm/day, ... 
#> time (days) : 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31
```

So we're dealing with a stack of daily global precipitation data, consisting of 366 layers. It's quite convenient that this stack already has the time attribute properly defined, but so has your SST data.

```r
terra::time(r) |> head(10)
#>  [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" "2020-01-05"
#>  [6] "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-09" "2020-01-10"
```

Assuming you already imported your locations features using `sf`, you can now do the following:

```r
# create random point for extraction
p <- sf::st_point(c(6.1, 50.5)) |> 
  sf::st_sfc(crs = "epsg:4326") |> 
  terra::vect()

# extract values from raster stack based on feature input
values <- terra::extract(r, p, ID = FALSE) |> as.double()

# get timestamps
datetimes <- terra::time(r) |> as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

# create xts object
xts <- xts::xts(values, order.by = datetimes)

# inspect
plot(xts, type = "h", col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for that, that's very helpful. There are a couple of questions I'd like to ask. When I extracted my points the resulting df is wider than longer, meaning my 8271 time points are a column each instead of rows. When I've tried creating the xts object I got an error saying: Error in xts::xts(SST0022v1, order.by = datetimes) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
> NROW(SST0022v1)
[1] 6304
> NROW(datetimes)
[1] 8271

Is there any way I could make both match and create the xts object?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, I've discovered some of my points have NA values. Is there any way within the extraction proces that I could point out that if a value is an NA to give me the closest neighboring value? or and average of the closest ones?

Thanks!

Comment: When you're dealing with ~13,000 nc files representing daily data, you should end up with a SpatRaster object with nlyr ~13,000, if `terra` is able to handle this size, but I guess you'll notice otherwise due to error messages. Is this sth you can confirm after running `list.files(pattern = "nc$") |> terra::rast()` in the relevant directory?

Comment: Sorry, I was running this for a subset so I only took data from 01-01-2000 onwards, so I have a total of 8271 layers in my current stack. My observations came from ~6000 lat and long points, so when I extracted my point from my raster I've got a df of ~6000 rows x  8271 columns. Whereas the datetimes object is a column of 8271 rows. I think that's the issue when trying to run your next step, the xts line of code

Comment: Oh, you're right. My workflow encompassed looping over individual points only with some post-processing included, that's why I went for `as.double()` here and did not continue with the resulting data.frame. You're right - the number of columns/variables corresponds to the number of layers of your raster and the number of rows/observations to the number of points used for extraction. If you apply `t()` on the resulting data.frame and use this as input of `xts::xts()` instead of `values`, you should get an xts object with n columns corresponding to the number of points used.

Comment: Generally, it is probably not the worst idea to start small and advance step by step. So maybe don't use all your data all at once but start with subsets (raster, points) in order to understand the behaviour of the individual functions. Regarding the `NA` values - do they occur in space or in time? Ergo, are some of your points not covered by the SST dataset at all? Or do they occur occasionally as part of the timeseries due to some gaps in the data? This would result in different methods to eliminate gaps in the data.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've used the transpose function and worked perfectly.

The NAs occur in space, there are some points that might fall within pixels that might have been classed as land, other data I've checked and it's actually in land hence the NA values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146406/discussion-between-dimfalk-and-rgr-288).